# Как правильно сверстать такой блок?

Tags: html, css

Как правильно сверстать блок со скрина, чтобы:

1. Круг выше блока ровно на 50% своей высоты.
2. Круг в виде div, которому задано изображение в виде background-image.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: «Правильно» зависит от конкретных требований к вёрстке. Можно хоть тупо PNG-картинкой это сделать, вдруг это тоже считается «правильно»)

Comment: Еще не понятно фиксированная ли ширина блок и круга, тут это очень важно

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev нет, ширина изначально не известна...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Адаптивно правильный вариант такой:

```css
.item {
  background: lightgrey;
  width: 30%;
  margin-top: 20%; /* это не рабочее число */
  padding: 10px;
}

.item .thumb {
  width: 100%;
  background: purple;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  margin-top: calc(-50% - 10px);
  margin-bottom: 10px; /* возвращаем padding блока */
}

.item .thumb:before { /* делаем резиновый квадрат */
  content: '';
  display: block;
  padding-top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <div class="thumb" style="background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ed/Double_Peaked_Ararat.jpg/400px-Double_Peaked_Ararat.jpg)"></div>
  Как правильно сверстать блок со скрина, чтобы: Круг выше блока ровно на 50% своей высоты. Круг в виде div, которому задано изображение в виде background-image.
</div>
```

Единственное, вылетает картинка выше контейнера всего блока, поэтому отступ надо делать отдельно в зависимости от разметки